# Character self collision

Tags: modeling

I've been doing a lot of research on character collision on YouTube and Google, but there seems to be no answers out there on how to "cure" a character of "self collision".

Is there some type of modifier I should use, or is there some programming I have to do? I have no idea how to get past this.

Comment: What kinds of characters and collisions are you talking about? Is this about the Blender Game Engine? Does this involve animation or physics? What do you mean by self collision and how is it a problem? If you could edit your question and elaborate on your issue a bit that would be fantastic.

Comment: Show your issue with such collisions... maybe someone will understand and suggest something...

Comment: Animation. I've been working on this character for 2 weeks now, and I've previously seen unsightly pulling, bending, tears, and now and again arms or legs going through the characters other body parts. I would send you a picture of what I mean, but this doesn't have anything for me to submit a picture for what's happening.  I hope that clarifies. Thanks :)

Comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/s/Triston%20McCoy/top